# Storing data line by line into arrays

Tags: c++

I need to store data into two arrays that are stored in the order Name then Number

Ex:

```
Kara

000131012

Tucker

002102000
```

I understand how to use the single-line method:

```
while (infile >> a >> b)
{
    // process pair (a,b)
}
```

But this doesn't work for the way this data is stored.

Comment: Similar recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059747/storing-data-from-txt-that-has-inputs-on-seperate-lines)

Comment: As long as each line contains only one word, this will work. In other cases look at `std::getline`.

Comment: Given the input sample provided I can't see why this code would fail. More information, use [mcve] as inspiration, could help this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The pair will not represent a number/name pair consistently anymore if the name contains spaces.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think there is a misunderstanding. I assumed n314159 was referring to the code in this question.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What does it do differently than what you want?

Comment: I, on the other hand, assumed that n314159  wasn't a Standard draft. Be really busy beavers if it was.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I indeed did refer to the code in the question. It will break if the names contain a space. If every unit we want to read consists of one word, the code will work regardless if there are 3 words in each line or 42 words separated by tabs. The space characters between words do not matter at all.

Comment: @n314159 Duh! (slaps my own forehead) - Some days I manage to misunderstand just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how sensible it is to add an answer so late (and to this easy question), but I want to be clear since there were some missunderstandings in the comments.

**How does `>>` work?**

The `operator>>` first discards als leading space characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, maybe more, this depends on the locale). Then it will try to read as many non-whitespace characters as possible (so `int i; cin >> i;` with input `123123jj` sets `i` to `123123`). Then it will potentially set the failbit, eofbit, or badbit, which influence the boolean value of the stream.

**What does that mean for your code?**

If your names consistenly do not include a space character, your code will run perfectly completely independent of the number of words per line. If you have that guarantee of spaceless names, I would recommend this way since it is easy and you don't get a problem if your input is a bit faulty and has for example a double newline at some point.

If you have perhaps spaces in the names, your code above will fail. Then you have to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Its usage is well documented on the linked page.